# Rhythm Box Control key Not working when trying to select songs

Tags: keyboard, rhythmbox

For some reason when trying to select select individual songs from a list of songs o add to a play list, the control key is not functioning. I can select a group of contiguous songs with the shift key, no problem.
NOTE: The control function works great in other apps.
I am running 22.04, and as far as I can tell  everything is running the most current version of everything. I.E. no beta code.
So what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Rythmbox just doesn't support that. You can file a feature request at the [issues page](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues) and while you wait, you can try a different music player app like [Music](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Music) that is also created by GNOME. I checked, and it supports Ctrl+Click.

Comment: It might not now but it used too. When I first started using Ubuntu I know it worked. I used it a lot. Sometime between 18.XX and 22.04 I had a crash and had to start over. And when I finely got everything back Rhythm Box had lost some of my play lists. Not all of them, but the (of course) I listen to the most....